# How to blend motions with Mecanim

Tags: unity, mecanim

I'm struggling with Mecanim.

My concern is to blend straight/turning animations with strafe animation for a humanoid character.

I downloaded a SampleAsset from unity and took Ethan character as example. The animator uses a blendtree which naturally blend idle/walking/running animations with a smooth turning left/right animations. In this case the Ethan character cannot strafe.

I'm trying to understand how to blend strafe movement with it's actual straight/turning blending motion.

Was I somewhat clear?

Comment: What have you tried, what were the results, and what symptoms are you trying to correct? An image of your current animation graph, and a video showing the blending behaviour you have now will help a lot in diagnosing what you need to change.